# Deprecation Warning for Squeel load_core_extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deprecated, squeel

in one of my applications I get the annoying deprecation warning of squeel all the time.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Core extensions are deprecated and will be removed in Squeel 2.0. (called from app/config/initializers/configurations/squeel_init.rb:13:in `block in <top (required)>')
```

It is produced by this line:

```
config.load_core_extensions :hash, :symbol
```

We are running `* squeel (1.2.3)`.

Any ideas how to avoid this message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I want to say that the reason why you are getting the WORKING is to let you know that if you upgrade your gem to squeel (2.0) the Core Extensions will not work.

I think if you upgrade your gem to squeel (2.0) you will have to remove that line.

I hope that you have test in place to see where you need to upgrade your app.

> Deprecation is an attribute applied to a computer software feature,
>   characteristic, or practice to indicate that it should be avoided
>   (often because it is being superseded).